# How to use Typescript Accessors in ngOnInit in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a getter and a setter propertie, and I want to use that in the ngOnit of Angular.

The Typescript Accessors looks like this:

```
         if (modelValue) {

    }
```

and I have the ngOnit like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    }
```

and the constructor looks like this:

```
    }
```

But now I get this error:

Comment: Hi, edit your question. What Error?

Answer (score 0):

You don't an object for the pipe.

```
  constructor(readonly textResourceService: TextResourceService,readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {
    super(textResourceService, route);
    }
```

Should help.

Comment: Thank you. But what actually do you mean?

Comment: I have added private readonly formatPipe: FormatPipe in the constructor see the code above

Comment: You don't need to explicitly declare an object for the pipes. Once a pipe is declared in the app.module.ts (declaration), you can use the pipe name all over the application.